# When to use defer function in react-router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Can anyone explain with simple examples when to use `defer` utility exported in `react-router`? When a plain promise is returned from a loader function it seems to behave the same way as in case of deferred value. From the react-router source code it looks like there is a lot of wrapping and handling around deferred data, but I don't quite get the purpose of it and differences in the 2 examples I've put in the following codesandbox
Here is an example code https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sun-wztcpc?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

## Commentary/Clarity

It would seem that mixing in the `Suspense`/`Await` code syntax for non-deferred route loaders does indeed make them act very much the same, or very similar. In your code example though, for the non-deferred example, this is an incorrectly used loader and UI component.

| Non-Deferred Loaders | Deferred Loaders |
| --- | --- |
| Can be `async` | Are not `async` |
| Can `await` asynchronous calls | Don't/can't `await` asynchronous calls |

A more accurate representation would be as follows:

```
const AsyncValRead = () => {
  const data = useAsyncValue();
  return <p>{data}</p>;
};

const AsyncValRead2 = () => {
  const data = useLoaderData();
  return <p>{data.normal}</p>;
};
```

```
const Abb = () => {
  const data = useLoaderData();
  return (
    <>
      <h3>Example router with defer</h3>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<p>Loading data #1...</p>}>
        <Await resolve={data.normal} errorElement={<p>Oh no...</p>}>
          <AsyncValRead />
        </Await>
      </React.Suspense>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<p>Loading data #2...</p>}>
        <Await resolve={data.crash} errorElement={<p>Oh no...</p>}>
          {(v) => <p>{v}</p>}
        </Await>
      </React.Suspense>
    </>
  );
};

const Abb2 = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h3>Example router without defer</h3>
      <AsyncValRead2 />
    </>
  );
};
```

```
const router1 = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      path="*"
      loader={() => {
        return defer({
          normal: sleep(4000, "router1 success promise"),
          crash: sleep(3000, "router1 failed promise", true)
        });
      }}
      element={<Abb type="with defer" />}
    />
  )
);

const router2 = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      path="*"
      loader={async () => {
        return {
          normal: await sleep(4000, "router2 success promise"),
        };
      }}
      element={<Abb2 />}
    />
  )
);
```

[image: Edit when-to-use-defer-function-in-react-router-v6]

Notice how the deferred route is immediately loaded and the UI does the "waiting" for the data to resolve while the non-deferred route waits for the data to load ***in the loader*** and ***then*** rendere the route and route content.

## Question

> ...when to use `defer` utility exported in `react-router`?

As stated above, when using route loaders ***normally*** the route and routed content isn't rendered until the asynchronous code in the loaders resolve and data can be provided to the route. If the asynchronous calls are slow and/or heavy, it can make your app appear to be slow and sluggish, all without providing any feedback to the user that "stuff" is actually going on behind the scenes. The user either sees a blank page or the current page while this is going on.

This is where deferred loaders come into play as they allow you to ***immediately*** render the route and provide some fallback UI/feedback to the user. If you haven't already read through the [Deferred Data Guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/deferred) then I highly suggest giving it a good read-through or three.

### TL;DR

Use deferred route loading when you would like to provide some immediate UI and feedback to the user that a page and data is loading when normal loading is (*subjectively*) too slow.

Comment: You explain it so COMPLETE! I think they should refer to your answer in their docs! :)